# Zerizin Makdimin or Brov Am

Tags: halacha, priorities, zerizut-alacrity, rov-am

If you have a choice of doing a Mitzva earlier and being Mekayem Zerizin Makdimin or doing it later and at that point there would be more people doing the Mitzva together and thus you would gain Brov Am - which choice is the better option?

Answer (score 3):

Hacham Ovadia Yosef in Yabia Omer Vol. 2 (Yoreh Deah 18) rules that if you have an option to make a Berit Milah later in the day and more people will come, you should still do it earlier because zerizin makdimim lemitzva takes precedence over berov am hadrat melech. (If, in this specific case, he won't have a minyan unless he waits till later in the day, Hacham Ovadia rules that he should wait, because doing the Milah with a quorum takes precedence over zerizin makdimim lemitzva.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the mishna brurah says if you daven shachris on shabbos early at a house minyan, you should wait for later mussaf at the big shul, due to b'rov am.

Clearly each situation will have its own tradeoffs.

Comment: Source?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​